# TypeError: 'module' object not callable

Tags: python, pygame

I have searched thoroughly before posting this. I seem to have a 'module' object not callable error. Here is my code:

```
""" Create Snake """
def createSnake():
    x = randrange(0, 720, 20)
    y = randrange(0, 480, 20)
    size = 3
    snakeBox = ""
    snake = []
    for i in range(size):
        snakeBox = pygame.rect((x + 20*size, y + 20*size), (20, 20))
        snake.append(snakeBox)
    return snake
```

This is the error I recieve on execution:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/Codes/Snake# python Snake.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Snake.py", line 108, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
File "Snake.py", line 106, in main
    gameScreen()
File "Snake.py", line 95, in gameScreen
    game()
File "Snake.py", line 57, in game
    snake = createSnake()
File "Snake.py", line 49, in createSnake
    snakeBox = pygame.rect((x + 20*size, y + 20*size), (20, 20))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I cannot seem to figure out what the error is as I think I have imported my modules correctly

```
from pygame.locals import *
```

Thank you for your help :')

Comment: `pygame.rect` is itself a module, not an object. That module contains a `Rect` object, which is what you do want to call. See falsetru's answer.

Comment: Thank you @TheSoundDefense. That makes sense. I shall brush up on my pygame skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likes a simple typo of [`pygame.Rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html).

Replace:

```
pygame.rect
```

with:

```
pygame.Rect
```

Comment: Thank you @falsetru. I was completely oblivious to this fact. I require more pygame programming practice to stop making errors like these. Thank you again.