# Python: Object not callable - runs in Notebook but not in PyCharm

Tags: python, pytorch, callable

EDIT: I could solve it (hopefully it does what I want). But I don't understand why it works now. I put my workaround at the bottom. Would be great, if somebody could enlighten me, why it works (or why notebook worked without it).

---

I use the code from this tutorial:

https://amaarora.github.io/posts/2020-09-13-unet.html#understanding-input-and-output-shapes-in-u-net

and it runs in my Notebook code.

Now I try to adapt this code for my model. Thus, I copy it in my model.py which has an only class AENet and adapt it accordingly. But PyCharm already raises the warning that

> object 'Encoder' is not callable
> object 'Decoder' is not callable

And the program breaks when I call it from the terminal.

Before:

```
class AENet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,input_dim, block_size):
        super(AENet,self).__init__()
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.cov_source = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(block_size, block_size), requires_grad=False)
        self.cov_target = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(block_size, block_size), requires_grad=False)

        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.input_dim,128),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(128,momentum=0.01, eps=1e-03),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(128,8),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(8,momentum=0.01, eps=1e-03),
            nn.ReLU(),
        )

        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(8,128),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(128,momentum=0.01, eps=1e-03),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(128,self.input_dim)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        z = self.encoder(x.view(-1,self.input_dim))
        return self.decoder(z), z
```

and after my copy+paste and adaptation of the AENet class it looks like this

```
class Block(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_ch, out_ch):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_ch, out_ch, 3)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(out_ch, out_ch, 3)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.conv2(self.relu(self.conv1(x)))


class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, chs=(1, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024)):
        super().__init__()
        self.enc_blocks = nn.ModuleList([Block(chs[i], chs[i + 1]) for i in range(len(chs) - 1)])
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2)

    def forward(self, x):
        ftrs = []
        for block in self.enc_blocks:
            x = block(x)
            ftrs.append(x)
            x = self.pool(x)
        return ftrs


class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, chs=(1024, 512, 256, 128, 64)):
        super().__init__()
        self.chs = chs
        self.upconvs = nn.ModuleList([nn.ConvTranspose2d(chs[i], chs[i + 1], 2, 2) for i in range(len(chs) - 1)])
        self.dec_blocks = nn.ModuleList([Block(chs[i], chs[i + 1]) for i in range(len(chs) - 1)])

    def forward(self, x, encoder_features):
        for i in range(len(self.chs) - 1):
            x = self.upconvs[i](x)
            enc_ftrs = self.crop(encoder_features[i], x)
            x = torch.cat([x, enc_ftrs], dim=1)
            x = self.dec_blocks[i](x)
        return x

    def crop(self, enc_ftrs, x):
        _, _, H, W = x.shape
        enc_ftrs = torchvision.transforms.CenterCrop([H, W])(enc_ftrs)
        return enc_ftrs


class AENet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, block_size, enc_chs=(1, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024), dec_chs=(1024, 512, 256, 128, 64), num_class=1,
                 retain_dim=True, out_sz=(256, 640)):
        super(AENet,self).__init__()
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.cov_source = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(block_size, block_size), requires_grad=False)
        self.cov_target = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(block_size, block_size), requires_grad=False)
        self.encoder = Encoder(enc_chs)
        self.decoder = Decoder(dec_chs)
        self.head = nn.Conv2d(dec_chs[-1], num_class, 1)
        self.retain_dim = retain_dim
        self.out_sz = out_sz

    def forward(self, x):
        print(f'FOR X: we have the dimensions {x.shape}')
        z = self.encoder(x[None, None, :])
        print(f'FOR Z: we have the dimensions {z.shape}')
        out = self.decoder(z[::-1][0], z[::-1][1:])
        out = self.head(out)
        if self.retain_dim:
            out = F.interpolate(out, self.out_sz)
        print(f'FOR O: we have the dimensions {out.shape}')
        return out, z
```

My workaround:

```
z = self.encoder.forward(x[None, None, :])
out = self.decoder.forward(z[::-1][0], z[::-1][1:])
```

Why do I need to call the class' method directly, while it works straight as above in jupyter notebook?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'module' object not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185842/typeerror-module-object-not-callable)

Comment: This does not help me. I have tried it, and it didn't work

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the rror.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you solved this, but when I encountered the same problem I found that my `python interpreter` was not configured for pycharm.  Once that was set it correctly found the `nn.Module` subclasses to be callable.